# Is there any way to enable scrollbars for RecyclerView in code?

Tags: android, scrollbars, android-recyclerview

As we saw, RecyclerView is more effective than ListView, so I prefer to use it in my project. But recently I have a trouble when put it in my custom ViewGroup. RecyclerView is easy to set scrollbars in xml like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

But I really can't find any method to set the scrollbars in code for RecyclerView, what I have tried is:

```
mRecyclerView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```

and then I saw [this](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html#computeHorizontalScrollExtent(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.State)) in Android's document.

So I tried to make my own LayoutManager and override the functions which I thought I need. But finally I failed. So can anyone tell me how should I make my own LayoutManager or just show me an other solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 147, accepted):

At the moment it seems to be impossible to enable scroll bars programmatically. The reason for that behaviour is that Android does not call either `View.initializeScrollbarsInternal(TypedArray a)` or `View.initializeScrollbars(TypedArray a)`. Both methods are only called if you instantiate your RecyclerView with an AttributeSet.
As a workaround I would suggest, that you create a new layout file with your RecyclerView only:
`vertical_recycler_view.xml`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Now you can inflate and add the RecyclerView with scrollbars everywhere you want:
`MyCustomViewGroup.java`

```
public class MyCustomViewGroup extends FrameLayout
{
    public MyCustomViewGroup(Context context)
    {
        super(context);

        RecyclerView verticalRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.vertical_recycler_view, null);
        verticalRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        addView(verticalRecyclerView);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now you can add scrollbars easily! Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39125108/3162918

Answer (score 88):

Set the vertical scrollbar in the xml layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Comment: Is this enough, or do we also have to set `android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"`?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky No need to set it, unless you want to specify if your scrollbar would be overlaid or inset

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, since OP didn't use XML layout at all and thus, wanted to have this programmatically.

Comment: And you have optional attributes such as `android:fadeScrollbars="true"`

Answer (score 46):

Just in xml properties

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" <!-- type of scrollbar -->
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/darker_gray"  <!--color of scroll bar-->
    android:scrollbarSize="5dp"> <!--width of scroll bar-->

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: how can set color from by scroll ? like recyclerview.scrollview.color = R.color.some_one

Answer (score 20):

I would prefer to use `ContextThemeWrapper` for that, because it can be used dynamically from code.

First define in Style.xml:

```
<style name="ScrollbarRecyclerView" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="android:scrollbars">vertical</item>
</style>
```

And then whenever you initialize your RecyclerView use `ContextThemeWrapper`:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = new RecyclerView(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.ScrollbarRecyclerView));
```

Answer (score 10):

You can do it without inflating an XML layout, but you'll need to declare a custom theme attribute and a style:

```
<resources>
    <attr name="verticalRecyclerViewStyle" format="reference"/>

    <style name="VerticalRecyclerView" parent="android:Widget">
        <item name="android:scrollbars">vertical</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then set the value of the attribute to the style in your theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="verticalRecyclerViewStyle">@style/VerticalRecyclerView</item>
</style>
```

Now you can create the RecyclerView programmatically with a vertical scrollbar:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = new RecyclerView(context, null, R.attr.verticalRecyclerViewStyle);
```

Answer (score 8):

Use a code like:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
 android:id="@+id/categoryRecyclerLayout"
 android:layout_width="414dp"
 android:layout_height="652dp"
 android:scrollbars="vertical" .... />
```