# Setting scrollbars property in RecyclerView crashes my app

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I recently started using RecyclerView replacing older ListView. But whenever I use `android:scrollbars="vertical"` in `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` element, my app crashes with the following error: 
`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.canScrollVertically()' on a null object reference`

This is how I'm using RecyclerView:

```
View rootView;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
    RecycleViewAdapter adapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(myRecyclerViewAdapter);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And this is `my_fragment.xml` file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Everything works perfectly fine if I don't use `android:scrollbars="vertical"`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27056379/is-there-any-way-to-enable-scrollbars-for-recyclerview-in-code

Comment: @JigneshJain I did try adding `android:scrollbars="vertical"` and it crashes my app, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: check this https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78545

Comment: @JigneshJain According to the forum, the problem was with older versions of support libraries. I'm using 22.0 with my project. Let me try changing it to 21.0.2 to see if it solves the problem.

Comment: @JigneshJain Nop. Did that. Still crashes.

Comment: Can you create a bug report on b.android.com with full stack trace? I thought i've guarded all places but maybe something is missing. Also, an easy workaround would be setting a layout manager when onCreateView is called.

Comment: @yigit Let me look into b.android.com
Could you elaborate setting a layout manager in `onCreateView` part. I would have to initialize RecyclerView at the same time, yes?

Comment: Assuming recyclerview is inside my_fragment, it is already initialized when you inflate it.

Comment: Not technically. FrameLayout is defined in a separate file and RecyclerView in an another. An activity is inflating fragments.

Answer (score 0):

When using the `RecyclerView` you don't really need to specify the `scrollbars` display; it is the `LayoutManager` job where you specify if it is Vertical or Horizontal orientation and of course the scrollbar display will automatically change whatever orientation you choose.

```
//for vertical scrollbar and orientation
LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);  

//for horizontal scrollbar and orientation 
LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
```

Comment: I just tried it and it still doesn't show scrollbars.

Comment: @BasitSaeed how big is the list?? is it big enough to have a scrollbar?

Comment: It has 7 elements and yes, it is big enough to have a scrollbar as content gets overflowed.

Comment: @BasitSaeed what is in your gradle? for implementing the recylerlistview

Comment: I'm using SDK version 22 with following dependencies
    `compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'`