# Can not see scroll bar in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollbar

I want to design a `custom scrollbar` but I can't even see the scrollbar in `recyclerview`, here is my code and I have also followed this question but not able to get the answer from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376224/scrollbar-not-showing-in-recyclerview)

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:scrollbarSize="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Comment: How many items do you have in your list?

Comment: 25 items @Eenvincible

Comment: add right margin to recyclerview

Comment: No change @YoLo

Comment: This link may help you. See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27056379/is-there-any-way-to-enable-scrollbars-for-recyclerview-in-code

Comment: What is the background color of the whole view?

Comment: Also, enable `fadeScrollbars` true. Make sure you have enough items in the list and lastly If it doesn't work, try enabling recyclerView fast scrolling.

Comment: Gr8 @Debdeep , it is working now the background color was white but I did not write that. When i write android:background="@android:color/white" it is working. I dont know how

Comment: nice to hear that! did you check your `colors.xml` file ?

Comment: @Debdeep yes but color.xml has only default colors

Comment: The color that you were using earlier, what was it?

Comment: That was default color @Debdeep, I did not use any. btw can you do me a favor, actually as per my question I want to design a scrollbar using the custom image, can you guide me how to do? please look at the design of scroll bar [Image link](https://ibb.co/eDmKdm)

Comment: There are tutorials where you can see how to create a custom thumb drawable for scrollbars. Please post it a question in a new thread with your code in case you face any difficulty.

Answer (score 7):

you can Increase the size of **scrollbar**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:margin="5dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" <!-- type of scrollbar -->
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/darker_gray"  <!--color of scroll bar-->
    android:scrollbarSize="5dp"> <!--width of scroll bar-->

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: @Sudhansu Sekhar Try this let me know

Comment: No change @Gowthaman

Comment: @SudhansuSekhar **android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"** try this

Comment: No not working Gowthaman

Comment: I removed it but still not working

Comment: @SudhansuSekhar post your java code

Comment: I solved it @Gowthaman thanks

Comment: @SudhansuSekhar happy to hear that....please share your answer so that it will use full for some other people...

Comment: I did nothing just change the background color and it worked for me Gowthaman, I want to answer this question but how to answer my own question? I cant find the option.

Comment: where would I write-in question only?